# what is the difference between Asynchronous class and thread and when use thread or Asynchronous in android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, handler, runnable

I am little bit confuse when to use Asynchronous class or thread ( new Runnable()) or Runnable Interface when trying to post some data to server or get some data from the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) says:

> A Thread is a concurrent unit of execution. It has its own call stack
>   for methods being invoked, their arguments and local variables. Each
>   application has at least one thread running when it is started, the
>   main thread, in the main ThreadGroup. The runtime keeps its own
>   threads in the system thread group.
>
> There are two ways to execute code in a new thread. You can either
>   subclass Thread and overriding its run() method, or construct a new
>   Thread and pass a Runnable to the constructor. In either case, the
>   start() method must be called to actually execute the new Thread.

So, `Runnable` just represents a command that can be executed in the thread. Concurrent equations are made in threads anyway (`AsyncTask`, for example, also using thread inside itself).